# Queue eneque function with C++

Tags: c++, queue

I've been trying to solve this queue program in C++ simulating an airport.
When I use enqueue function below, the program stucks and doesn't give any error messages.
I think the error is in the line "this->front = newNode;" but I can't figure out anything more.

Thanks in advance!

```
bool Queue::enqueue(Plane p) {
Node *newNode = new Node;
newNode->priority = 6 - p.getFuel();
newNode->plane = p;
newNode->next = 0;
if (this->length < 6) {
    if (this->length == 0) {
        this->front = newNode;
    } else {
        cout << "this->length != 0\n";
        this->rear->next = newNode;
    }
    this->rear = newNode;
    this->length++;

    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Just FYI, C++ has <vector>, <list> and even <queue> so you don't have to reinvent!

Comment: Yeah but I was trying to do something on my own just for an experience and faced this issue.
Thanks for the concern though.

Answer (score 0):

Using standard C++ <queue> template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

// Substitute your definition here
typedef int Plane;

typedef std::queue <Plane> Runway;

int main()
{
    Runway runway;
    Plane plane(42);

    // En-queue
    runway.push(plane);

    // Who is ready?
    std::cout << runway.front() << std::endl;

    // De-queue
    runway.pop();

    return 0;
}
```

In your case, you might want to look into <priority_queue>.